# Apache Druid failing to connect to zookeeper, Apache Druid are deployed as docker image in one container

Tags: docker-compose, docker-network, druid, docker-swarm-mode

I am trying to deploy Apache -Druid in docker container. Image is built successfully. All the services including zookeeper are starting normally when Docker Image of Apache-druid is deployed.

Here is my setup, I am deploying Druid docker image on Docker remote host, it using Docker swarm internally. Ihave configured different container name, hostname for each service of Apache Druid. I have configured external network, I found out internally swarm is initiating those service on different hosts. I have configured "link" as zookeeper for Druid services and vice versa.

But, middle-magaer, co-ordinator and Broker are failing to connect to Zookeeper. Following is the error:

> org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/IP Address:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) 2020-03-19T22:04:05,673 INFO [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zookeeper/IP Address:2181.: Connection refused

So I have different services running on Docker network, on different
   nodes(Docker on Linux).
   These services are part of Apache Druid like middle manager, broker,router etc.  These services are part on one single docker
   compose file. 
Services start but then not able to connect to
   zookeeper which is part of Apache Druid package. Found out from my
   infra team that these services are launched on different nodes within
   network. 
I have used defined external network.  Also, I am defining
   links . How do I configure services to talk to each other. Here is my
   docker compose.
 Here is my docker-compose file in comment below

Request inputs.

Thanks and Regards, Shubhada

Comment: here is my docker compose file:

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue y setting druid host to gateway.docker.internal